# why is it Unable to find layout by ironlayout?

Tags: meteor

I am Meteor newbie so please bear with me on this question. I am creating a simple app, which shows list of poems on the left hand side panel and based on user selection, I show the poem on the right hand side panel. I am building this on my Mac with Meteor 1.0 and latest version iron:router. 
The program works fine and it is doing exactly what I am expecting it to be. When I say, works as I expected means, when I launch the page, I see the home page shown on the right hand panel. As the user makes the selection in the left hand panel, appropriate poem shows up in the right hand panel. But if I open the developer tools in Chrome I see two errors. They are

- "Uncaught Error: No Iron.Layout found so you can't use yield"
- "Uncaught Error: Can't render the same view twice"

Here is my Router configuration

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', function() {
   this.render('Home');
});

Router.route('/poems/:_id', {
  name: 'poemDetails',
  data: function() { return Poems.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

and here is my layout:

```
<template name="layout">
   {{> header}}
   <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
      <div class="row">
         <div>{{> poems}}</div>
         <div class="col-md-8">{{> yield}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: have you tried with a different name for your layout template? try myPageLayout or something.

Comment: good suggestion. Tried different name without putting the actual name in the template and made sure ironrouter threw error. It did throw and error as unable to find it. Then I put the layout as my layout and showed the content properly still has both the errors.

Comment: OK, I just replicated this, filling in the missing pieces and templates, and I do NOT get any errors. Can you post all your code?

Comment: sure thing, I will put it in Git and update it here. Thanks

Comment: put the project at https://github.com/ksunair/twopanel

Comment: First try to remove the entire <body> .... </body> from your client/main.html Iron Router replaces the body, you must not call the layout template manually

Comment: @Jamgold yes that was the problem(removing entire body). Could you please put that as answer, so I can mark it as answer for anyone looking for the same problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the entire  ....  from your client/main.html Iron Router replaces the body, you must not call the layout template manually